# MongoDB referred value not being updated

Tags: mongodb, express

I'm using ExpressJS + MongoDB + TypeScript. Below are the models I have

---

```
export class Author {
    name: string;
    dob: Date;
}
```

---

```
export class Publisher {
    name: string;
    address: string;
}
```

---

```
import {Author} from './Author';
import {Publisher} from './Publisher';

export class Book {
    name: string;
    price: number;
    author: Author;
    publisher: Publisher;
}
```

---

I've inserted the data as below

```
let publisher1: Publisher = new Publisher();
publisher1.name = "Publisher 1";
publisher1.address = "Amritsar";

let publisher2: Publisher = new Publisher();
publisher2.name = "Publisher 2";
publisher2.address = "Bangalore";

let author1: Author = new Author();
author1.name = "Author 1";
author1.dob = new Date();

let author2: Author = new Author();
author2.name = "Author 2";
author2.dob = new Date();

let book1: Book = new Book();
book1.name = "Book 1";
book1.price = 50;
book1.author = author1;
book1.publisher = publisher1;

let book2: Book = new Book();
book2.name = "Book 2";
book2.price = 100;
book2.author = author2;
book2.publisher = publisher2;

let book3: Book = new Book();
book3.name = "Book 3";
book3.price = 150;
book3.author = author1;
book3.publisher = publisher2;
```

There are 3 collections created i.e. Publisher (2 docs), Author (2 docs) and Books (3 docs).

Now when I update the name of **Author 1** to **Author 5** using the below code, it gets changed in the Author collection.

```
this.db.collection('Author').findOneAndUpdate({
    name: "Author 1"
}, {
    $set: {
        name: "Author 5"
    }
})
```

But when I query Book with name **Book 1** or **Book 3**, it still refers to the name **Author 1** instead of **Author 5**

Is there something wrong while referring to documents in the Book collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying that the `author` field in Book schema has a schema the same as the Author schema.  When you create a book and pass an author record to it as the value of the field `author`, you are setting the values directly in the Book record.  It is not linking the two records together.  In order to update the name in both records, you would have to update the name in the Author collection and the name for every corresponding record in the Book collection.

Comment: I read more on the problem and found that there is a different approach to handle this. The one I'm trying is incorrect. Thanks for the help.